# C compose unsigned 32-bit integer from four 8-bit integers

Tags: c, avr-gcc

On an 8-bit platform, I am composing an unsigned 32-bit integer from 4 8-bit integers like this:

```
uint8_t buf[4];
uint32_t large = 0;
large |= ((uint32_t)buf[0]) << 24;
large |= ((uint32_t)buf[1]) << 16;
large |= buf[2] << 8;
large |= buf[3] << 0;
```

Without the casts the compiler understandably complains:

```
bmp.c:100:23: warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
  100 |     large |= (buf[1]) << 16;
      |                       ^~
```

Are these casts expensive (I would guess yes) and can this be done more efficiently?

Here is what I think is the relevant disassembly from `avr-gcc (GCC) 13.2.0`:

```
000060ee <.L29>:
        large |= ((uint32_t)buf[1]) << 16;
    60ee:       91 2c           mov     r9, r1
    60f0:       a1 2c           mov     r10, r1         
    60f2:       b1 2c           mov     r11, r1

000060f4 <.Loc.91>:
        large |= buf[3] << 0;   
    60f4:       a9 2a           or      r10, r25
    
000060f6 <.Loc.92>:
        large |= buf[2] << 8;
    60f6:       50 e0           ldi     r21, 0x00       ; 0
    
000060f8 <.Loc.93>:
    60f8:       54 2f           mov     r21, r20
    60fa:       44 27           eor     r20, r20
    60fc:       05 2e           mov     r0, r21 
    60fe:       00 0c           add     r0, r0
    6100:       66 0b           sbc     r22, r22
    6102:       77 0b           sbc     r23, r23

00006104 <.Loc.94>:
        large |= buf[3] << 0;
    6104:       84 2a           or      r8, r20 
    6106:       95 2a           or      r9, r21 
    6108:       a6 2a           or      r10, r22
    610a:       b7 2a           or      r11, r23
    610c:       b8 2a           or      r11, r24
    610e:       80 92 04 01     sts     0x0104, r8      ; 0x800104 <large>
    6112:       90 92 05 01     sts     0x0105, r9      ; 0x800105 <large+0x1>
    6116:       a0 92 06 01     sts     0x0106, r10     ; 0x800106 <large+0x2>
    611a:       b0 92 07 01     sts     0x0107, r11     ; 0x800107 <large+0x3>
```

Comment: Why should they be expensive? Isn't it what you want? You *can't* shift an 8-bit value 24 times without promoting it to 32-bit first.

Comment: The compiler promotes values smaller than `int` size before arithmetic operations anyway. The cast's only purpose is to silence the warnings.

Comment: Now it really depends on the compiler, its optimizations, and the target system. It could be something to just silence the compiler, and the code generated would still be the same. *Or* it could cause a copy into four bytes of memory, and then a copy from that memory into the destination memory. Or something else completely. Only way to find out is to build with optimizations enabled and look at the generated machine code and what it does there.

Comment: It's a general-purpose warning, in case the target variable is also 8-bit size.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Re “The cast's only purpose is to silence the warnings”: The hell it is. First, OP’s compiler message indicates they have a 16-bit `int` (the right operand of the shift is 16, and the message says “left shift count >= width of type”). Second, you need to convert to an unsigned 32-bit type or a wider signed type to avoid overflow in shifting `buf[0]`; leaving it at a 32-bit `int` will not do it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I stand corrected that promotion to `int` won't do, but your assertion that the target has 16-bit `int` is bizarre. There would be a similar warning for the `<< 24` which is not posted.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Testing on Compiler Explorer shows that `sizeof (int)` for AVR gcc 13.2.0 is two bytes.

Comment: I would add that it might be relevant to take care of the endianness in your conversion as well.

Comment: I added the disassembly to the question. I wonder why there is no (obvious) access to `buf[0]`? On the AVR, the size of an `int` is 16-bit.

Comment: @WeatherVane You'd need the cast on a 32 bitter too, since something like `0x80 << 24` invokes undefined behavior, whereas `(uint32_t)0x80 << 24` does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The single expression you suggest yields 15 instead of 20 instructions
> if I am interpreting the disassembly correctly - nice!

No - it is a problem of the undefined/implemetation defined behaviour in the code, when it is written correctly it does not matter.  I would also suggest using pointer notation in parameters (as C passes arrays as pointers) and declare parameters as `const` if function is not changing them. It helps compiler with optimizations (even abstracting from [const correctness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const_(computer_programming)))

```
uint32_t foo(const uint8_t *buf)
{
    uint32_t large = 0;
    large |= ((uint32_t)buf[0]) << 24;
    large |= ((uint32_t)buf[1]) << 16;
    large |= (uint32_t)buf[2] << 8;
    large |= buf[3] << 0;
    return large;
}


uint32_t bar(const uint8_t *buf)
{
    return (uint32_t) buf[0] << 24 | (uint32_t) buf[1] << 16 | (uint32_t) buf[2] << 8 | buf[3];
}
```

Both generate the same machine code:

```
foo:
.L__stack_usage = 0
        mov r30,r24
        mov r31,r25
        ld r22,Z
        ldd r23,Z+1
        ldd r24,Z+2
        ldd r25,Z+3
        rcall __bswapsi2
        ret
bar:
.L__stack_usage = 0
        mov r30,r24
        mov r31,r25
        ld r22,Z
        ldd r23,Z+1
        ldd r24,Z+2
        ldd r25,Z+3
        rcall __bswapsi2
        ret
```

https://godbolt.org/z/b7o4114EP

Also AVR compiler assumes [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and you "composing" the uint32_t number from the big-endian representation.

If endianness match then I would suggest using `memcpy`

```
memcpy(&large, buff, sizeof(large));
```

Optimizing compilers will not call `memcpy`

```
uint32_t bar(uint8_t buf[4])
{
    uint32_t large;
    memcpy(&large, buf, sizeof(large));
    return large
}

bar:
.L__stack_usage = 0
        mov r30,r24
        mov r31,r25
        ld r22,Z
        ldd r23,Z+1
        ldd r24,Z+2
        ldd r25,Z+3
        ret
```

But to more interesting using **`union`s** makes code much more efficient if the `buf` data is big endian

```
uint32_t foo(const uint8_t *buf)
{
    union 
    {
        uint32_t large;
        uint8_t small[4];
    }d = {.small = {[0] = buf[0], [1] = buf[1], [2] = buf[2], [3] = buf[3]}};
    return d.large;
}

uint32_t bar(const uint8_t *buf)
{
    union 
    {
        uint32_t large;
        uint8_t small[4];
    }d = {.small = {[0] = buf[3], [1] = buf[2], [2] = buf[1], [3] = buf[0]}};
    return d.large;
}
```

and the resulting code:

```
foo:
.L__stack_usage = 0
        mov r30,r24
        mov r31,r25
        ldd r23,Z+1
        ld r22,Z
        ldd r24,Z+2
        ldd r25,Z+3
ret
bar:
.L__stack_usage = 0
        mov r30,r24
        mov r31,r25
        ldd r23,Z+2
        ldd r22,Z+3
        ldd r24,Z+1
        ld r25,Z
ret
```

Comment: Indeed it does not matter. I like the `memcpy` suggestion but endianess needs to be swapped.

Comment: @TorstenRömer in this case it is implementation defined and it is also an example of how bitshifts are if **signed** integers are used (even implicitly)

Comment: @TorstenRömer AVR gcc likes union punning. See the amended answer.\

Comment: So many ways - bitshift, memcpy, union... I go for the union one, since it is the fewest instructions and the smallest executable. Thank you for teaching me about unions!

Comment: Note however that the union version converts from big endian to either little or big endian. The shift version converts from big endian to the native endianess, portably.

Comment: @Lundin why do you think that the union version is not portable?

Comment: Because the byte order changes depending on CPU endianess.

Answer (score 2):

> Are these casts expensive (I would guess yes)…

No.

> … and can this be done more efficiently?

Knowledge of idioms for merging bytes into a multiple-byte word using shifts and ORs has long been built into GCC. However, because `int` is 16 bits in the C implementation you are using, you need a cast on `buf[2]` as in:

```
uint32_t bar(uint8_t buf[4])
{
    return (uint32_t) buf[0] << 24 | (uint32_t) buf[1] << 16 | (uint32_t) buf[2] << 8 | buf[3];
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised the optimizer can't get the repeated compound assignments right.

Comment: The single expression you suggest yields 15 instead of 20 instructions if I am interpreting the disassembly correctly - nice!

Comment: @TorstenRömer single expression and the compound one will compile to identical code unless undefined or implementation-defined behaviour is invoked in one of them like in this example

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, one can use vector types which is GNU-C:

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>

// A vector of 4 x uint8_t.
typedef uint8_t __attribute__((vector_size(4))) v4u8_t;

uint32_t func1 (const uint8_t *buf) {
    v4u8_t v4 = { buf[1], buf[0], buf[3], buf[2] };
    
    return (uint32_t) v4;
}
```

avr-gcc v13 generates the following code with `-Os -mmcu=atmega8`:

```
    movw r30,r24
    ldd r22,Z+1
    ld r23,Z
    ldd r24,Z+3
    ldd r25,Z+2
```

Sadly, with v14 there are no more four 1-byte loads but one 32-bit load with additional code:

```
    movw r30,r24
    ld r22,Z
    ldd r23,Z+1
    ldd r24,Z+2
    ldd r25,Z+3
    rcall __bswapsi2
    movw r18,r22
    movw r22,r24
    movw r24,r18
```